# Java TA-Lib Documentation

Tags: java, documentation

I was looking for a documentation on [TA-Lib](http://www.ta-lib.org/index.html) in Java. I have found the [page](http://www.ta-lib.org/function.html) containing the list of available functions, and found [this](http://tadoc.org/).

I see [TADOCS](http://tadoc.org/) provided the algorithms on some of the functions. However I was not able to understand the required parameters for the function, it does seemed to be mentioned. Is there anywhere where I could find it ?

Specifically, I was looking more for

```
LINEARREG       Linear Regression
```

Eclipse specifies linear regression as :

```
linearReg(startIdx, endIdx, inReal, optInTimePeriod, outBegIdx, outNBElement, outReal)
```

Is there anywhere I could refer to ?

**EDITED**

The other thing I am unclear is how do I specify the values of `TA_INTEGER_DEFAULT` or `TA_REAL_DEFAULT` if they are not used ?
I see this in the [c++ docs](http://www.ta-lib.org/d_api/d_api.html)

`If you do not care about a particular optIn just specify TA_INTEGER_DEFAULT or TA_REAL_DEFAULT (depending of the type).`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use linearreg like that:

```
    double reg_result;
    MInteger begin = new MInteger();
    MInteger length = new MInteger();
    c = new Core();
    RetCode retCode = c.linearReg(0, intLRLength-1, dataset,intLRLength, begin, length, high_reg);

    if(retCode == RetCode.Success){

        console.getOut().println("reg_result"+reg_result);  

        }
```

You can also look at the [Ta-lib c++ documentation](http://www.ta-lib.org/d_api/d_api.html) to get an idea of how the functions are implemented.

Comment: so here, I assume 
  `startIdx    = the start index for the data`,
  `endIdx      = the end index for the data`,
  `inReal      = the dataset`,
  `optInTimePeriod  = intLRLength (?)`
  `outBegIdx   = begin point of the output (?)`
  `outNBElement  = length of the output (?)`
  `outReal     = high_reg (the output ?)`

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, I added like this:

Dim TA_INTEGER_DEFAULT as Integer = Int32.Min
Dim TA_REAL_DEFAULT as Double = -4E37