# Implementing TA-lib in SciChart

Tags: android, scichart

I am trying to build an Android app with **SciChart**, the chart shows different types of **Technical Analysis Indicators**. I am trying to implement TA-Lib (http://www.ta-lib.org/) in SciChart using Android.

I had to Refer many Site to implement the **Ta-Lib** in **SciChart** but none have them worked for me, There is no proper documentation of TA-Lib in Java.

so please help me with this.

Comment: This probably isn't really on topic for this site. My advice is go ask the authors of this library or start writing some code and bootstrap yourself. If it's an opensource library you can inspect the code.

Comment: TA-Lib is open source, SciChart is commercial, it's actually not supported by SciChart to show you how to integrate TA-Lib to scichart. 

I would suggest looking around the web for various open source technical indicator libraries in Java or for Android. If you find one, it should be easy to integrate to SciChart's charting lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of googling I found a [Technical Analysis library for Java here](https://github.com/mdeverdelhan/ta4j-origins).

There are also examples for integrating [TA-Lib to java here](https://github.com/ishanthilina/TA-Lib-Java-Examples) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172882/java-ta-lib-documentation).

I'd suggest finding the right TA library that generates the indicator results you need. After that it is the simple action of plugging these variables into [SciChart's DataSeries](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/Tutorial%2003%20-%20Adding%20Series%20to%20a%20Chart.html).

**UPDATE:**

I recently found the open source project **[lppkarl/Trady](https://github.com/lppkarl/Trady)**, which has .NET Technical Indicators and won't require wrapping the indicator code in C# Platform/Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

SciChart has now published an open-source technical indicator & financial charts library for native Android (Kotlin) and iOS (Swift)

Find out more details here:
https://www.scichart.com/blog/open-source-financial-chart-library-for-ios/

The Android repo (OSS) is here:
https://github.com/abtsoftware/finance.android

This integrates to TA-Lib under the folder [finance/src/main/java/com/scitrader/finance/indicators/](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/Finance.Android/blob/release_v1/finance/src/main/java/com/scitrader/finance/indicators/TALibIndicatorProvider.kt)